# gazebo does not load simple model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created a simple `.world` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.4">
    <world name="office">
        <include>
            <uri>model://sun</uri>
        </include>

        <include>
            <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
        </include>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

My launch file also adds a robot to this world. It launches fine in gazebo, I can see the gray ground plane with grid markings on it and also my robot.
[image: image description]

Next I created a simple building layout (some walls created using Gazebo's building editor). I saved the building model and added these lines to my `.world` file:

```
<include>
    <uri>model://car_description/models/tunnel</uri>
    <pose>25 20.2 0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
```

When I launch the file again, this time it takes ages to launch. I see a 'Preparing your world ...' screen for a long time (~10 mins):
[image: image description]

and then I see this dark screen:

[image: image description]

Other solutions which I have tried and **did not work** for me are:

1. Adding the following code to the package's `package.xml`

   ```
    <export>
       <gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>
          <gazebo_ros gazebo_media_path="${prefix}/models"/>
    </export>
   ```
2. Adding the environment variable `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`to my `.bashrc` file:

   ```
    export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=/home/my_user/my_catkin_ws/src/
   ```

There are no errors thrown in the terminal. What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20229/gazebo-does-not-load-simple-model/) by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6243/subodh-malgonde/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I placed the model files in the `~/.gazebo/models` directory and changed the code in the `.world` file to:

```
<include>
    <uri>model://tunnel</uri>
    <pose>25 20.2 0 0 0 0</pose>
</include>
```

Its working fine now. However I still don't know how to provide a reference to models which are not in the `~/.gazeo/models` directory.

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6243/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 31 on 2018-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-08-13**:
What is the output of "echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH"?

**Comment by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6243/subodh-malgonde/) on 2018-08-23**:
This environment variable is not set by ROS. So the output is blank. After I set it in `.bashrc`, I get the output. However it did not fix my problem.

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-08-23**:
Try changing the command set in .bashrc slightly: export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}:/home/my_user/my_catkin_ws/src/
The difference here is that this adds your custom path to the existing model path (which should be ~/.gazebo/models) and doesn't overwrite it, allowing both paths to be used.